# Hermitian invertible sheaf on a Riemann surface.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory, riemann-surfaces, complex-manifolds

Let $X$ be a projective Riemann surface, and denote with $\mathscr O_X$ the sheaf  of regular functions (the strucure sheaf) and with $\mathscr O_{X^{an}}$ the sheaf of holomorphic functions on $X$. Clearly $\mathscr O_X\subset\mathscr O_{X^{an}} $.

An Hermitian invertible sheaf $\mathscr L$ on $X$ is a locally free sheaf of rank $1$ such that for each point $x\in X$ there is an Hermitian metric $h_x$ on the complex vector space $L(x):=\mathscr L_x\otimes_{\mathscr O_x} \mathbb C$. Moreover these metrics $h_x$ vary smoothly on $X$.

Now my question is:

> is $\mathscr L$ a sheaf of $\mathscr O_X$-modules or of $\mathscr
> O_{X^{an}}$-modules? Of course if the answer is the latter, then the definition of $L(x)$ has to be changed as well.

It seems that books adopt the convention that $\mathscr L$ is a  $\mathscr O_X$-module (see for example Miranda's book), but there is a problem with this. We loose the equivalence between hermitian invertible sheaf and hermitian line bundles! Indeed we are considering only line bundles with regular transition functions.

Comment: If you're working on compact Riemann surfaces then there is an equivalence between the two: $\matscr{L}\mapsto \mathscr{L}^\text{an}$. Of course, if you want to put a Hermitian metric on it then you want to be working with $\mathscr{L}^\text{an}$ which is a $\mathcal{O}_X$-module. I think you have a bit of a misunderstanding as for notation. Namely, if $X$ is a Riemann surface then $X$ is not even necessarily algebraic! So, when one writes $\mathcal{O}_X$ they MEAN the sheaf of holomorphic functions.

Comment: Yes, I have to add projective.

Comment: I still think that if one says '$X$ is a Riemann surface' then $\mathcal{O}_X$ MEANS the sheaf of holomorphic functions. If someone says $X$ is a smooth projective algebraic curve then $\mathcal{O}_X$ means the sheaf of algebraic functions, and $\mathcal{O}_{X^\text{an}}$ means the sheaf of holomorphic functions on the Riemann surface $X^\text{an}$. If one says '$X$ is an object of category $\mathscr{C}$' and $\mathscr{C}$ is some category of locally ringed spaces, then $\mathcal{O}_X$ means the structure sheaf. Algebraic geometry=sheaf of alg. functions, Riemann surfaces= sheaf of hol. functs

Comment: Ok, your last comment is crystal clear. By the way, let's stay in the case of projective Riemann surfaces. Is there any difference if we consider algebraic line bundles or holomorphic line bundles? I think that the answer is yes, the former are a subset of the latter

Comment: It depends by what you mean 'is there a difference'. Yes, of course, there is a difference. They aren't even line bundles on the same locally ringed space. Namely, if $\mathscr{L}$ is a line bundle on $X$, a smooth projective algebraic curve, then $\mathscr{L}$ is locally (for the ZARISKI topology) isomorphic to $\mathcal{O}_X$. If $\mathscr{M}$ is a line bundle on $X^\text{an}$ then $\mathscr{M}$ is (COMPLEX locally) isomorphic to $\mathcal{O}_{X^\text{an}}$. Even if one ignores the different topologies they can't be the same since $\mathcal{O}_X\ne \mathcal{O}_{X^\text{an}}$. That said,

Comment: there is an isomorphism $\mathrm{Pic}(X)\cong\mathrm{Pic}(X^\text{an})$ given (informally) by $\mathscr{L}\mapsto \mathscr{L}^\text{an}:=\mathscr{L}\otimes_{\mathcal{O}_X}\mathcal{O}_{X^\text{an}}$. So, while the line bundles aren't equal (they aren't even literally subsets of one another) the isomorphism classes of such objects are isomorphic by the analytification functor.